# How to define test-only dependencies?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Rust library that implements a lint plugin. I want to include `compiletest`, but not require it outside of testing. What is the correct way to specify that the dependency is for testing only?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Yes. Use `dev-dependencies`. From the [Cargo docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#development-dependencies):

> You can add a `[dev-dependencies]` section to your `Cargo.toml` whose format is equivalent to `[dependencies]`:
>
> ```
> [dev-dependencies]
> tempdir = "0.3"
> ```
>
> Dev-dependencies are not used when compiling a package for building,
> but are used for compiling tests, examples, and benchmarks.

When possible, you should also use Cargo's [resolver version 2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#resolver-versions) to better handle complicated dev-dependency cases.

Comment: There is any command to add dev dependency like in Yarn: "yarn add xyz"?

Comment: @TomaszWaszczyk [Is there a command to automatically add a crate to my Cargo.toml?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32934310/155423). `cargo add --dev xyz`