# Is there a command to automatically add a crate to my Cargo.toml?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I expected there to be something like: `cargo install stopwatch` but could not find it in the docs.

Finding the package version and manually adding the package to .toml:

```
[dependencies]
stopwatch="0.0.6"
```

Does not feel automated enough. :)

Comment: this is an [update](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5586) on that matter, in case someone is also wondering if the answer is outdated

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, there is no such thing built in to Cargo. There is only a `cargo install` subcommand which installs the binaries of a crate *system-wide*.

New third-party [Cargo subcommands](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/wiki/Third-party-cargo-subcommands) can be created, and [cargo edit](https://github.com/killercup/cargo-edit), does what you want.

These cargo subcommands can then be installed by `cargo install`, in a fun meta circle!

```
% cargo install cargo-edit

# Now `cargo add` is available
% cargo add mycrate
```

Comment: Ok, was just curious and had the feeling of missing something obvious.

Comment: @JohanLarsson oh, look at my last edit; it might be up your alley.

Comment: mildly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63744854/how-to-link-gtk-from-rust

Comment: im just finding my way around rust and this seems like a strange omission from cargo - still, solution found, ty

Answer (score 27):

As of Rust 1.62.0, you can use the following command to add dependencies, avoiding you to open the .toml file.

```
cargo add dependency@version
```

More info here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/commands/cargo-add.html

Comment: `@version` is optional. By default, cargo picks up the latest version of the dependency. Thought of adding this since the question mentions "finding the package version".