# How to link gtk from Rust?

Tags: rust

I'm using the GTK provided Rust example from https://www.gtk.org, and am wondering how to nail down GTK as a dependency (or other type of prerequisite) so that the Rust program given there will build with cargo.

Here's the code, copied from there without modification:

```
use gio::prelude::*;
use glib::clone;
use gtk::prelude::*;

// When the application is launched…
fn on_activate(application: &gtk::Application) {
    // … create a new window …
    let window = gtk::ApplicationWindow::new(application);
    // … with a button in it …
    let button = gtk::Button::new_with_label("Hello World!");
    // … which closes the window when clicked
    button.connect_clicked(clone!(@weak window => move |_| window.close()));
    window.add(&button);
    window.show_all();
}

fn main() {
    // Create a new application
    let app = gtk::Application::new(Some("com.github.gtk-rs.examples.basic"), Default::default())
        .expect("Initialization failed...");
    app.connect_activate(|app| on_activate(app));
    // Run the application
    app.run(&std::env::args().collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

As is, without any `Cargo.toml` definitions for gtk, gtk symbols will not resolve when compiling the program.

How would you go about it most idiomatically?

I do have GTK installed on my system of course.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you put the dependency in your [project's `Cargo.toml`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#choosing-features)?

Comment: My question takes aim at how to figure the dependency name (give or take select a sane version such as the one present on one's system) of a C library, in this case gtk, as opposed to a rust dependency. Apologies for the newb question.

Comment: And does [this page](https://gtk-rs.org/docs-src/tutorial/version) answer that question?

Comment: As mentioned [on the GTK website](https://www.gtk.org/docs/language-bindings/rust/), that example code is using several GTK crates from the [`gtk-rs`](https://gtk-rs.org/) project; that is what is needed to get it to build. You can't just directly use a C library with Rust; you have to set up FFI to make it work, and for something as big as GTK, that's a *lot*. Take a look at the [source code for the `gtk` package](https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk) if you're interested in how that works.

Comment: If you're asking about the _process_ of finding the correct dependency, that depends on your starting point. In this case you started with an example from gtk.org, so I'd expect to find the information about the Rust bonding there. And indeed, clicking on "docs" (under a hamburger-like menu on the mobile rendition of the site), then on "language bindings", and then "Rust" takes me to [this page](https://www.gtk.org/docs/language-bindings/rust/) which explains that the Rust bindings are covered by the `gtk-rs` crate and links to its documentation. Is that the information you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks everyone, despite the minor condescending tone it helped in building the big picture before going into the details. And [reading some more](https://medium.com/dwelo-r-d/using-c-libraries-in-rust-13961948c72a) about rust's bindgen I begin to get the picture of why getting the bindings on one's own is not a trivial single tool command.

Comment: I have posted a real answer myself. Any comments to it are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Rust can call code using the C ABI, but as @Herohtar explains, it is not automatic. You need to give the compiler the information about the `extern "C"` functions to be able to call them.

For commonplace libraries, there may be existing bindings out there. These are Rust library crates that contain all the glue already written for you. They work like any other Rust dependency that you put in your `Cargo.toml` file.

Answer (score 0):

So indeed I ended up following the suggested approach of using the [gtk-rs](https://gtk-rs.org/) rust integration project rather than pursue any gtk wrapper of my own. My initial source of confusion has been that [the gtk website](https://www.gtk.org/) just gave the gtk-rs sample code without any reference or mention of the gtk-rs project being assumed.

The public crate which that code assumes, even though not explicitly stated in the original code sample page, is called gtk; I guess that's the default naming convention: that the namespace and crate name are typically the same.

Including that crate in the build indeed satisfies the `gtk` namespace appearing in the code. And the same trivial naming convention applies for the `gio` and `glib` namespace requirements appearing in the sample code. They all seem to come from [the gtk-rs project](https://github.com/gtk-rs), though unlike other programming languages, this is not explicitly evident in the crate specification as only the name of the create, not the project containing it, are specified in cargo.

As to versions, I have chosen the most recent version of the gtk crate (as per suggestion from my VSCode rust plugin) and the newest crate feature providing support for GTK's latest supported API.

And I have also arbitrarily plucked versions of the gio and glib crates off another gtk-rs project hoping for seamless interoperability between the last two and the gtk crate itself, as they seem to need to be separately specified and not brought in by the gtk crate itself.

So with the following dependency definitions in my Cargo.toml, the sample code works:

```
[dependencies]
gtk = { version = "0.9.2", features = ["v3_22"] }
glib = "0.10"
gio = { version = "0.9", features = ["v2_56"] }
```

I'm new to rust but I might at present time think some of this is more complicated than it could be or would be in the case of other rust projects, or, that using the sample code assumes familiarity with the compatibility scheme of gtk-rs crates or that of the underlying native compatibility of gtk with glib and gio versions!

The latter aspect might be simple enough but not explicitly discussed [where gtk-rs documentation discusses versioning](https://gtk-rs.org/docs-src/tutorial/version).

An odd sticking point for me was that the following method had to be replaced by me with the one following it, perhaps this code sample is just slightly outdated compared to the latest version of the crate (?!).

provided code sample:

> gtk::Button::new_with_label

actual method that is defined:

> gtk::Button::with_label