# How do you include all crates in a workspace inside the test directory?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a binary Rust project which uses the workspaces to manage sub-crates.

**Directory structure**

```
/myapp
  Cargo.toml
  /src
  /tests
    test.rs
  /crates
    /printer
      Cargo.toml
      /src
```

**myapp/Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "myapp"

[workspace]
members = ["crates/printer"]
```

Inside of `test.rs` I can compile `extern crate myapp;` to pull in the parts of the application that are exposed in `src/lib.rs`. This works as expected.

However, when attempting to compile `extern crate printer;` it errors that it cannot find it. I've confirmed that the printer package is correctly placed in the top-level `Cargo.lock` file.

How do I include my sub-crates into the `/tests` directory at the top level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing special about workspaces or even the concept of tests. If you want to use a crate in Rust code, you have to add it as a dependency:

```
[dependencies]
printer = { path = "crates/printer" }
```

See also:

- [How to define test-only dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29857002/155423)

Comment: So, I did try that and it seemed to mess up the shared dependency nature of workspaces. When I add in the printer crate as a dependency, I then need to add its dependencies to its `Cargo.toml`. It stops sharing the dependencies with the root crate.

Comment: @garrettmaring *I then need to add its dependencies to its Cargo.toml* — yes; that's how it is **supposed** to work. The point of a workspace is to ensure that all the members have the same version of the compiled dependencies (a unified **Cargo.lock**). Each crate in a workspace is supposed to define its own **Cargo.toml**; otherwise where would you define things like the crate name? You may wish to re-read the [Cargo docs about workspaces](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-workspace-section). Perhaps file a bug if you think the docs are unclear.

Comment: If a dependency is only used in tests, it should be defined in `[dev-dependencies]` rather than in `[dependencies]`.